# Rspec rails unit test - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have this code for unit test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'fetch_controller'

   RSpec.describe FetchController, type: :controller do
   it "parse base 64 url" do
     result = FetchController.parse_urls('aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29t')

    expect(result[0]).to eq('http://www.google.com')

   end
 end
```

and I want to test parse_urls method that in fetch_controller:

```
class FetchController < ApplicationController
...
  def parse_urls(base)
  Base64.decode64(base).split(',')
end
```

But when i'm trying to run it I get an error
 ": in `require': cannot load such file -- fetch_controller (LoadError)"

Thanks for any help,
Yoel

Comment: Did you try to remove `require 'fetch_controller'` line?

Comment: have you written file named 'fetch_controller'.?

Comment: I have fetch_controller under the app.
Should I write another one under spec?
and if so, what should I write in the file:

'    class FetchController
    def initialize


  end
end '

I din't understand how to initialize it.

Thanks!

Comment: @Joel you shouldn't require controllers by hand, it should be done by rspec.

Comment: @dimakura,  I removed the require controller but I get uninitialized constant FetchController

Comment: show your rails helper

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov

rails_helper.rb:

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'


ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end

Comment: does your controller file lie in `app/controllers/fetch_controller.rb` and your spec in `spec/controllers/fetch_controller_spec.rb` ?

Comment: no, my controller file lie in 'app/controllers/api/fetch_controller.rb' and my spec in 'spec/controllers/api/fetch_controller_spec.rb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you use a namespace. Then, proper names are

```
class Api::FetchController < ApplicationController
```

and

```
RSpec.describe Api::FetchController, type: :controller do
```